# Difference between prototype and non-object methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Lets take a look at these two examples:

first:

```
function Cars (name, doors) {
    this.name = name;
    this.doors = doors;
    function getInfo() {
        return this.name + " " + this.doors;
    };
}
```

second:

```
function Cars (name, doors) {
        this.name = name;
        this.doors = doors;
    }

Cars.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.doors;
}
```

I know that in first example saving the `getInfo()` method as object instance would waste memory `this.getInfo() = function() { this.cars + " " + this.doors;}` and it would be inherited, but is there a difference if the method would be defined as a non-object property - like I did in the first example and not as an object instance (I'm missing words here), besides that it would be statically defined?

What is the difference between

`this.getInfo() = function() { 
     return this.cars + " " + this.doors;
}`

and

```
function getInfo() {
    return this.cars + " " + this.doors;
}
```

Performance and all other differences?

Also, is there a way to access private local variables with `obj.prototype`?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please see my final edit.

Comment: The second options (prototype) set's the function of all Cars objects. The first one only for that instance.

Comment: And no, it is not a duplicate..

Comment: The property option is using less memory (and bandwidth) if a lot of car objects are used. Don't think performance wise it's much different since they both are functions that to do same. But for such small functions you wouldn't notice unless you got a huge amount of car objects.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks, but what about my second question?

Comment: Sorry don't know that

Comment: Thanks mate for the first one. :)